# Send huge data through post request from oracle database

Tags: oracle, http, post, clob, utl-http

I am trying to send data via an HTTP post request from Oracle using UTL_HTTP.
The code is like this:

```
REQ := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(URL,'POST','HTTP/1.1')
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(REQ,'USER-AGENT','MOZILLA/4.0')
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(REQ,'CONENT-LENGT',LENGTH(V_BODY)
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(REQ,'CONTENT-TYPE','APPLICATION/JSON')
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(REQ,'SDATE','01/06/2021')

UTL_HTTP.WRITE_RAW(REQ,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(V_BODY)
RES := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(REQ);
UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(RES,BUFFER);
```

Inside the V_BODY parameter is a clob containing JSON
and this json I select from database then put in a clob.
Now the request is working fine when the selected data records about 50 to 100 request,
but I need to send one million records,
and when I trying sending such request it fails when putting the clob as a parameter.
It like the http request does not allow me to send such huge data.
What is the best way to handle this issue or is there a way to send it in smaller chunks?

Comment: you said it yourself, if possible break the data up and send in batches of json.  Hard to tell without a [mcve]

Comment: @William thanks dear I did it I will provide the snippet in a separate answer for others

Answer (score 2):

You can use a header to tell the target that you are going to send the data in chunks.

```
utl_http.set_header (l_request, 'Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
```

Then you send the data in batches using what carving up mechanism you like

```
utl_http.write_raw(l_request, [first 32k]);
utl_http.write_raw(l_request, [next 32k]);
```

etc etc.

If that doesn't work, it may be an issue with the receiver because not all web servers will happily accept chunked requests.

Comment: thanks dear I have done something like this and it does work but stuck in another place, the api I am trying to call is a rest api and inside it I call a soap service you could say that I am wrapping the soap service with a rest api, now when calling the rest from oracle it works and request reach to tomcat server but when call the soap inside it I got a java heap space error do I need also to chuck the soap service is there a way or it is better to try increase the heap size if it possible